# Principal component analysis on proportional data

Tags: pca

Is it valid to run a PCA on data that is comprised of proportions? For example, I have data on the proportion of various food items in the diet of different species. Can I run a PCA on this type of data or should I transform the data or do something else beforehand?

Comment: Thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question. You should search for ["compositional data analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data). There are transformation to apply to proportions in order to analyze them with multivariate tecniques such as PCA. You can find also ["robust" PCA](https://rdrr.io/cran/robCompositions/man/pcaCoDa.html) algorithms to run your analysis in R. Let us know if you find an appropriate solution to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

PCA will give you "impossible" answers. You might get principal components with values that proportions can't have, like negative values or values greater than 1. How would you interpret this component?

In technical terms, the support of your data is a subset of the support of PCA. Say you have $k$ classes. Then:

- the support for PCA vectors is $\R^k$
- the support for your proportion vectors is the $k$- dimensional simplex. By simplex I mean the set of $p$ vectors of length $k$ such that:

  - $0 \le p_i \le 1$ where $i = 1, ..., k$
  - $\sum_{i=1}^k{p_i} = 1$

One way around this is if there's a one to one mapping between the $k$-simplex to all of $\R^k$. If so, you could map from your proportions to $\R^k$, do PCA there, then map the PCA vectors to the simplex.

But I'm not sure the simplex is a self-contained linear space. If you add two elements of the simplex, you don't get an element of the simplex :/

A better approach, I think, is clustering, eg with Gaussian mixtures, or spectral clustering. This is related to PCA. But a nice property of clustering is you can express any element of your data as a "convex combination" of the clusters. If you analyze your proportion data and find clusters, they (unlike PCA vectors) will be within the simplex space, and any mixture of them will be, too.

I also recommend looking into nonnegative matrix factorization. This is like PCA but, as the name suggests, avoids negative components and also negative eigenvectors. It's very useful for inferring structure in strictly positive data, like proportions. But nmf does not give you a basis for simplex space.